# Build Sql query from a list of Ids

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to delete certain items from a table where `ids` are in the list.
So I need a query something like this:

```
delete from t
where id in ('46DE52AD-3481-E911-B94A-F48C506A31F9', '49DE52AD-3481-E911-B94A-F48C506A31F9' .... )
```

However I have a very long list and I do not want to sit and copy paste to build the query. There surely must be a way to read the list from a file and build the query..

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Load the file into a table and use a subquery.

Comment: Is this a simple text file? Is the list plain data, somehow delimited (CSV)? Do you know the files encoding?